# Comments should also be possible to original question, not only to answers!

Tags: bug, comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does the comment system and comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-does-the-comment-system-and-comments-work)

**CURRENTLY:**

I already encountered this situation quite often at stackoverflow.com.

Someone posts a question, but the question left some important aspects open!

With the current technical implementation at stackoverflow.com you can only create an answer, and start your clarification Q&A thread inside there. But structurally seen, this IS NOT A REAL answer, but rather some further callbacks and answers, before the REAL answer!

**SUGGESTION:**

Structurally, it would be very good if one could create a comment to the original question, within which one clarifies the meaning of the question, and then give a REAL answer into the answer section!

Comment: This is a comment on your question.

Comment: @balpha this is a follow-up on your comment asking for clarification.

Answer (score 7):

This functionality already exists. But **you need to have a reputation score of 50**, then you'll be able to comment as you are suggesting - and as balpha and Pekka have wonderfully demonstrated.

Check out the [Comments FAQ Section](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-does-the-comment-system-and-comments-work/19757#19757) for full details.

Answer (score 6):

This is a rep limitation. Since you have < 50 rep, you can only comment within your *own* question (question or answers), and on your own replies (in discussion). When you have >= 50 rep, you can comment anywhere. See the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) for the list of what rep you need for which site functions.